# How do my plugin get notified when editor.setData is done

Tags: ckeditor5

How do my plugin get notified when editor.setData is done?

I have a plugin which need to do some calculations on data, each time editor.setData is called.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to listen to all data changes in the editor and make some action after it, then you can do:

```
editor.model.document.listenTo( 'change:data', () => {
     // Perform some action.
}
```

Comment: editor.setData() doesn't fire any other events despite `change` and `change:data`. You can fire some custom event from the one plugin on some of the editor entities and listen to it from the other plugin.

Comment: It'd help if you could provide a bit more details on what you want to do, MTilsted. Right now it's hard to propose some other solution.

Comment: BTW, interestingly, first data load will fire `editor.data#init` because the `DataController#init()` method is decorated. We could decorate `DataController#set()` too but it'd be good to understand the use case.

Comment: @Reinmar The usecase is that I have made a custom plugin which need to do some content manipulation once data have been set. This plugin handles a fixed position custom element, which is always the first child of root, and which can not be added/removed by the user.

Comment: So, you should actually look into [post-fixers](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_document-Document.html#function-registerPostFixer). That's the safest place to implement such rules.

Comment: @Rainmar I don't think that will work. My code don't change anything in the model. It just need to copy part of the model, so it can restore it in case the user delete it. So it need to be run exactly once set data is done(So it have a copy of the structure as it looked when the document was loaded).   This is all part of me trying to create a kind of 'header' in the top of the document with a few fixed fields. Where the user can edit the fields but not delete them. (So delete operations, are detected and then my header is restored from the "saved copy" created at startup.